# jsessionid gets dropped between apache and tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat7

We use Apache 2.2.22 and tomcat 7.0.54 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.
Mod proxy is used and Apache and Tomcat run on same AWS instance.

We have observed that for the same request JSESSIONID can be seen in Apache access logs but tomcat logs it as "JSESSIONID=-" and this results in user being sent to login page.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?
This happens very rarely but its not that uncommon to ignore all together.

TIA,
Sameer